# Entity Framework - How to configure the User Roles Many to Many Relationship

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-code-first-mapping

Below is the definition of the **User** entity, there is a navigation property **Roles**

```
    public class User
    {
        public User()
        {
            Roles = new List<Role>();
        }

        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string Username { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
```

Below is definition of the **Role** entity

```
public class Role
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
```

What i want is to define the many to many relationship and generate a relationship table **UserRole** which use **UserId** as the left key and **RoleId** as the right key, so how to write the configuration code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**User:**

```
public class User
{
    public User()
    {
        Roles = new List<Role>();
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserRole> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

**Role:**

```
public class Role
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

**UserRole:**

```
public class UserRole
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string RoleId{ get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

Override the `OnModelCreating` method in your dbcontext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
        .HasMany(c => c.Roles )
        .WithMany()                 
        .Map(x =>
        {
            x.MapLeftKey("UserId");
            x.MapRightKey("RoleId");
            x.ToTable("UserRoles");
        });
}
```

Comment: Is the UserRole class needed?